# ggplot2: Passing new data argument per layer to reduce code redundancy

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I'm working in a project requiring many similar plots, I find myself rewriting very similar lines of `ggplot2`-code with minor adjustments. Since a lot of repetition usually means I'm doing something wrong (and is annoying and error prone) I'm looking for a more sensible workflow to work with `ggplot2`.

Layers which are identical between plots can be saved to variables and called via this variable:

```
library(ggplot2)
myPoints <- geom_point(data = mtcars, aes(disp,mpg, size = qsec, colour = cyl))

ggplot() +
  myPoints
```

But what if I want to recreate the same plot with a different dataset containing the same colums? If I'd work with one dataset, this would be simple (call in the initial `ggplot()`-command). But I have at least two datasets and want to recreate the same plot using the same styling, but just switching the input data.

```
# Creating a second dataset for the plot:
rectangle <- data.frame(minx= c(100,200),maxx= c(150,300),miny= c(15,30),maxy= c(18,32))

# Saving it to a layer:
myRectangles <- geom_rect(data = rectangle,aes(xmin=minx,xmax=maxx,ymin=miny,ymax=maxy))

# This creates my first plot with all data
ggplot() +
  myPoints +
  myRectangles
```

Now I'll create some new data:

```
mtcars_new <- mtcars[1:16,]
rectangle_new <- data.frame(xmin = c(100,200),xmax = c(150,300),ymin = c(15,30),ymax = c(18,32))
```

I would now like to recreate the first plot by simply passing on the new datasets to the following lines:

```
  ggplot() +
    myPoints +   # <- pass "mtcars_new" to this layer
    myRectangles # <- pass "rectangle_new" to this layer
```

I hope I could clarify what my aim is, I've put quite a lot of thought into this example.

Comment: You could access the data that is mapped by using `myPoints$data <- mtcars_new;
myRectangles$data <- rectangle_new`. However, this would require consistent variable names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is often the solution when using a functional language, use functions!

```
myPoints <- function(data)
    geom_point(data = data, aes(disp,mpg, size = qsec, colour = cyl))
myRectangles <- function(data) 
    geom_rect(data = data, aes(xmin=minx,xmax=maxx,ymin=miny,ymax=maxy))

ggplot() +
  myPoints(mtcars) +
  myRectangles(rectangle)

ggplot() +
  myPoints(mtcars_new) +
  myRectangles(rectangle_new)
```

You can also assign aesthetics to objects and reuse them

```
aes_point <- aes(disp,mpg, size = qsec, colour = cyl)
aes_rect <- aes(xmin=minx, xmax=maxx, ymin=miny, ymax=maxy)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes_point, data=mtcars) +
  geom_rect(aes_rect, data=rectangle)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution for you would be to create a plotting function. Something on the lines:

```
myplot_fun <- function(my_data_points, my_data_rect){
   p <- ggplot()
   p <- p + geom_point(data = my_data_points, aes(......), .....)
   p <- p + geom_rect(data = my_data_rect, aes(......), .....)
   print(p)  # if you want to immediately plot, and not "store" 
   return(p) # if you want to "store" the plot for later use
 }
```

then, you can call it with whatever data you want from you main script or console:

```
p1 <- myplot_fun(mydata_point1, mydata_rec1)
....
....
p2 <- myplot_fun(mydata_point1, mydata_rec2)
```

HTH !

Comment: Thank you sir! I had to accept MrFlicks reply for a slightly faster and more concise answer